# How to get a list of all pull requests in history from Azure DevOps Server API?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to get a list of all pull requests ever done for data analysis purposes. After I get this working, I plan to find out how to include which repo each PR belongs to, which work item, area path, etc...

````py
import os
import base64
import requests
import csv

# Set up your variables
org_url = "https://organization.com/collection"
project_name = "project"
PAT = os.environ.get('AzureDevOpsPAT')

# Set up the headers with the PAT, if available
headers = {}
if PAT is not None:
    headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(bytes(':' + PAT, 'utf-8')).decode('ascii')
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'

# Get all the pull requests in the project
response = requests.get(f"{org_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/pullrequests", headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
pull_requests = response.json()["value"]

# Write pull requests to a CSV file
with open('pull_requests.csv', mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['PullRequestId', 'Title', 'Description', 'Status', 'CreatedDate', 'CreatedBy']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for pull_request in pull_requests:
        writer.writerow({
            'PullRequestId': pull_request['pullRequestId'],
            'Title': pull_request['title'],
            'Status': pull_request['status'],
            'CreatedDate': pull_request['creationDate'],
            'CreatedBy': pull_request['createdBy']['displayName']
        })```
````

This code works but only returns what I believe to be the current PRs marked as active (in my case it's 64), not all PRs ever created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check this doc: [Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

There is `searchCriteria.status` to set needed pr statuses: [PullRequestStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#pullrequeststatus)

In your case, the link may look like this:

```
requests.get(f"{org_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=all", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks Shamrai, making this change definitely returned more data, but it's still very unexpectedly low.

I suspect that the API returns a limited amount of records if beginning and/or end date is specified in the API call. I haven't figured out how to do it yet but I'll get to it.